# Creating custom DOM events with scalajs

Tags: scala, scala.js

I can't find a way to create custom events with scala-js. For instance, with js you can create a custom event like the following (taken from here):

```
  var event = new CustomEvent('build', { 'detail': elem.dataset.time });
```

However, there is no constructor for `CustomerEvent` or `Event` in scala-js that accept arguments. Also, subclassing either such as:

```
  class DrawEvent extends Event {
    override def `type` = "draw"
  }
```

leads to

> Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

when trying to construct via `new DrawEvent()`

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To instantiate javascript classes in ScalaJs you have to use js.Dynamic.newInstance:

This should work for your use case:

`val event = js.Dynamic.newInstance(js.Dynamic.global.CustomEvent)("build", js.Dynamic.literal(detail = elem.dataset.time)).asInstanceOf[js.dom.CustomEvent]`

There is more info available at the remarks portion (all the way at the bottom) of:
http://www.scala-js.org/doc/calling-javascript.html

Here is the same solution using some imports to make it shorter

```
import js.Dynamic.{ global => g, newInstance => jsnew, literal => lit }
val event = jsnew(g.CustomEvent)("build", lit(detail = elem.dataset.time)).asInstanceOf[js.dom.CustomEvent]
```

Comment: what is the variable `elem`?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to stay in the typed DOM (assuming you are talking about the scala-js-dom library), you can do:

```
new CustomEvent().initCustomEvent('build', false, false, elem.dataset.time)
```

The constructor you are using is actually only specified in [DOM 4](https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/domcore/raw-file/tip/Overview.html) (see [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/CustomEvent#Constructor)).

Comment: This gives me: `scala.scalajs.js.JavaScriptException: TypeError: Failed to construct 'CustomEvent': 1 argument required, but only 0 present.`