# How to create a new object using new operator in ScalaJS?

Tags: scala.js

In javascript I can create a new object from a constructor, using the new operator. How can this be done in ScalaJS?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In answer to my own question, I discovered from here - [Creating custom DOM events with scalajs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24619945/creating-custom-dom-events-with-scalajs)

I'm using require within NodeJS, actually Atom-Shell but that's basically NodeJS.

The Javascript:

https://github.com/atom/atom-shell/blob/master/docs/api/browser-window.md

```
var BrowserWindow = require('browser-window');
var win = new BrowserWindow({ width: 800, height: 600, show: false });
```

The Scala equivalent is:

```
import js.Dynamic.{ global => g }
val browserWindow = js.Dynamic.newInstance(
     g.require("browser-window").asInstanceOf[js.Dynamic])(
     js.Dynamic.literal(width = 800, height = 600, show = false)
     )
```

Comment: Thank you so much for answering your own question, I was completely stuck on that one. Do you have any more code out there interacting with atom from Scalajs, that could be very helpful to me. Cheers!