# Using element.dataset in ScalaJS

Tags: scala.js

After using:

```
org.scalajs.dom.document.getElementById("myId")
```

to get an element, its `dataset` property is not available.

However, I have seen it used in another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24619945/creating-custom-dom-events-with-scalajs).

I have searched the source code tree of scala-js-dom for the `dataset` keyword, and have found nothing. What could I be missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hmm -- I agree that it doesn't appear to currently be in the DOM facade yet, possibly because it's relatively new. (According to caniuse, it looks like it only hit universal support recently. In general, features only go into scalajs-dom when all major browsers support them.)

Possibly the other example was using it dynamically? If "elem" in that example was a js.Dynamic, that code would be untyped, and looks like it would work.

I suspect that a PR to add it to scalajs-dom would be welcome at this point. In the meantime, you ought to be able to work around the lack by adding a supplementary facade, something like (note that this is untested):

```
@js.native
implicit class HTMLElementExt(elem:HTMLElement) {
  def dataset:js.Dictionary[String] = js.native
}
```